# Modifying the first element of each tuple in a list of list by getting a dictionary value

Tags: python, nlp

I have a long list of about 40 lists, and each list contain a certain number of tuples. Each tuple has an ID and a score. Here's what it looks like (I shortened it significantly for illustration purposes):

```
[[(31, 0.27253215992549495), (1, 0.19154703077923324), (2, 0.19154703077923324)], [(838, 0.23670500362094776), (849, 0.23670500362094776), (790, 0.19360388648088026),  (406, 0.05016758978027092), (486, 0.05016758978027092), (141, 0.045542436270797924)]]
```

Each id corresponds to an entry in a dictionary called `dictionary_en`, and I know I can convert the id (the the 1st element of each tuple) with `dictionary_en.get(id)`. I tried several ways to do so, but it seems to not be possible directly (tuples are immutable?), and trying to convert each tuple to a list, I get an error

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

What I want is to replace each id with `dictionary_en.get(id)`, so I end up with something like):

```
[[('precaution', 0.27253215992549495), ('avoid', 0.19154703077923324), (bag, 0.19154703077923324)], [('passed', 0.23670500362094776), ('shoe', 0.23670500362094776), ('air', 0.19360388648088026),  ('house', 0.05016758978027092), (eat, 0.05016758978027092), (talk, 0.045542436270797924)]]
```

I don't mind if each tuple needs to be a list instead.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
>>> id_to_word = {1:'Word 1', 2:'Word2', 3:'Word3'}
>>> id_to_val = [(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.3)]
>>> [(id_to_word.get(id), weight) for id, weight in id_to_val]
[('Word 1', 0.1), ('Word2', 0.2), ('Word3', 0.3)]
```

If dealing with 2D arrays, here's the code:

```py
>>> id_to_val = [[(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.3)]]
>>> [[(id_to_word.get(id), weight) for id, weight in ar] for ar in id_to_val]
[[('Word 1', 0.1), ('Word2', 0.2), ('Word3', 0.3)]]
```

Comment: It doesn't work directly, because id_to_val is more like `id_to_val = [[(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.3)], [(2, 0.3), (3, 0.7)]]`. The topples are in lists, nested in a big list. Your code gives me "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Comment: I tried `[[(id_to_word.get(id), weight) for id, weight in group for group in id_to_val]]`, but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: @DavidPepin updated code for 2D arrays. could you confirm if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. tuple is immutable. you can try `list(t)` to convert it to list. Or put the string and second value into a new list. Or use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
new_list = np.array(your_list)
```

it will convert all tuples to list automatically. then change whatever you want

Check it out:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_list = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)])
>>> my_list
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> my_list[1,1] = 0
>>> my_list
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 0]])
```

try to learn numpy, then in your case, you may be able do matrix operation instead of deep nested for loop.

Comment: I can convert each list individually, but I can't seem to find how to convert all lists within the list as arrays.

Comment: It shouldn't be, I added demonstration code in my answer, you can check

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm trying to learn basic NLP stuff, so matrix operations is likely a good idea.